# Sqoop import count differs (source vs destination)

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop2, sqoop

while sqooping (import) if the source table is getting updated, then does sqooped output row count is source table count at t=sqoop_start or t=sqoop_end

I am running shell script to verify if the data is properly sqooped from source table. But I see difference in one of the table which is sometimes +ve/-ve

Comment: It depends on how your source DB works. Sqoop uses plain JDBC, remember? >> recommended reading: Wikipedia, chapter **transactions**...

Comment: There's an "incremental" mode in Sqoop. For good reason >> recommended reading: the Sqoop **user manual**.